# Check for Duplicates on sales order(Customer PO) Save

Tags: javascript, web-services, netsuite

This is the code i created to warn the user but 70% of sales orders are being created by Web services( SPS commerce, Celigo). How do terminate the web service process( i don't wanna let web service to save the sales order) if the PO is already exist in system.

--> This code shows the message for all the sales order. its not checking for duplicate po number.
code:

```
function checkForDuplicates() {
    //Get the current form customer PO number to validate
    var customerpo = nlapiGetFieldValue('otherrefnum');
    var filters = new Array();
    //Create the search filter for that PO number
    filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('otherrefnum', null, 'is', customerpo);
    var results = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, null);
    if (results !== null) {
    //Is the result this record?
    if (results[0].getId() !== nlapiGetRecordId()) {
        //No, there is another record, ask user to confirm/cancel saving action
        var doWeSave = confirm('Sales Order with the PO number ' + customerpo + ' already exists.\n' +
            'Click OK to save a duplicate Sales Order.\n' +
            'Click Cancel to return to editing Sales Order.');
        if (doWeSave) {
            //User selected to save the record
            return true;
        }
        //User selected to cancel the save
        return false;
    }
}
//No duplicates
return true;
}
```

Hello i used below code but it still shows the message for all the sales orders.

```
function checkForDuplicates() {
    //Get the current form customer PO number to validate
    var customerpo = nlapiGetFieldValue('otherrefnum');

    //Create the search filter for that PO number
    var filters = [
   new nlobjSearchFilter('otherrefnum', null, 'is', customerpo),
   new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'), // filter to mainline makes results faster in many cases
   new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'))];
        var results = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, null);
    if (results !== null) {
        //Is the result this record?
        if (results[0].getId() !== nlapiGetRecordId()) {
        //No, there is another record, ask user to confirm/cancel saving action
        var doWeSave = confirm('Sales Order with the PO number ' + customerpo + ' already exists.\n' +
            'Click OK to save a duplicate Sales Order.\n' +
            'Click Cancel to return to editing Sales Order.');
        if (doWeSave) {
            //User selected to save the record
            return true;
        }
        //User selected to cancel the save
        return false;
    }
}
//No duplicates
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would edit this test so that it runs in a in a before Submit user event. In the case of a duplicate you would throw an error. You can leave the existing client code in place.

NOTE: you are not testing on customer. It is fairly common in a busy company for customer PO #s to be duplicates so you should probably include more filters. e.g:

```
var filters = [
   new nlobjSearchFilter('otherrefnum', null, 'equalto', customerpo),
   new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'), // filter to mainline makes results faster in many cases
   new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'))
];
```

Make sure your web services preferences are set to run user events

Setup -> Integration -> Web Services Preferences
make sure "Disable Server SuiteScript..." is NOT checked

The before submit user event script would look like:

```
function beforeSubmitDupeCheck(type) {
    if(type == 'create' || type == 'copy' || type == 'edit'){
        var customerpo = nlapiGetFieldValue('otherrefnum');
        if(!customerpo) return; // just end
        if(type == 'edit'){
            var oldRec = nlapiGetOldRecord();
            if(customerpo == oldRec.getFieldValue('otherrefnum')) return; // didn't change so no re-test
        }

        var filters = [
            new nlobjSearchFilter('otherrefnum', null, 'equalto', customerpo),
            new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'), // filter to mainline makes results faster in many cases
            new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'))
        ];
        if (nlapiGetRecordId()) {
            filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'noneof', [nlapiGetRecordId()]));
        }
        var duplicates = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid'));
        if (duplicates) throw nlapiCreateError('DUPE_PO', 'Duplicate PO number '+ customerpo +' found on Sales Order '+ duplicates[0].getValue('tranid'));
    }
}
```

The sample below could be used as a saveRecord client script that should work.

```
function checkForDuplicates() {
    //Get the current form customer PO number to validate
    var customerpo = nlapiGetFieldValue('otherrefnum');

    //Create the search filter for that PO number
    var filters = [
        new nlobjSearchFilter('otherrefnum', null, 'equalto', customerpo),
        new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T'), // filter to mainline makes results faster in many cases
        new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null, 'is', nlapiGetFieldValue('entity'))
    ];
    if(nlapiGetRecordId()){
        filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'noneof', [nlapiGetRecordId()]));
    }
    var duplicates = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filters, new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid'));
    if(!duplicates) return true;


    //No, there is another record, ask user to confirm/cancel saving action
     return confirm('Sales Order '+ duplicates[0].getValue('tranid') +' with the PO number ' + customerpo + ' already exists.\n' + 'Click OK to save a duplicate Sales Order.\n' + 'Click Cancel to return to editing Sales Order.');
}
```

Comment: It still shows message for all the sales orders. Please check the main post.

Comment: Hello Bknights, if i place this live, how web service will respond? will it terminate the process of creating the duplicate sales order or web service will ignore the message?

Comment: For managing the web services you have to use slightly different code. Seem my edited answer

Comment: Also thanks for your edit. I always forget that otherrefnum doesn't behave as it should. 'equalto' is not a valid string test. Somehow otherrefnum retains some legacy from years ago when it was just check number. Equalto is generally only valid in numeric tests.